# Help ID snake near Deming NM

Tags: species-identification, snake

[image]This snake is in our yard, south of Deming NM, in Luna County.
Approximate length is about 3 1/2 feet.
It moved slowly at the time, but was being picked on by a couple of medium-sized birds.
It is basically black with a black, narrow head.
The body and snout have pale yellowish markings.  On the body, the yellow is individual scales, so almost spotted.  And on the snout, more like lines or stripes.
I have some good photos, and even videos, but it says the files are too big - need to be under 2 giggleburps or something and I don't know how to do that.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/110283/discussion-on-question-by-idhelp-help-id-snake-near-deming-nm).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Though a full body image would help a lot, I feel certain that it is the desert king snake scientifically known as *Lampropeltis getula splendida*. This species is seen in most parts of New Mexico and is not venomous. It primarily feeds on rodents, lizards, birds, snakes and eggs.

Here's a link to a website with more details on this species and other snake species of New Mexico: http://www.nmherpsociety.org/reptiles/snakes/lampropeltisgetulasplendida/index.html

Here's a variety of different photos of the desert king snake from different angles (but different ages, sizes and pattern varieties of the same species).

[image]

[image]

[image]